# When did double-keying cease to be a common practice in verification?

Tags: history

In an IBM service bureau in the early 1960’s all data was keyed twice.  The first time the holes were punched into cards.  The 2nd time a verifier checked that the correct holes had been punched.  Even in the programmers’ office we had both machines and were expected to verify our debugging changes.

Today passwords are the only things we are asked to enter twice.

Comment: Probably at the time the cost of the extra manual effort for double-checking started to exceed the cost for wasted CPU time on unsuccessful batch jobs

Comment: Have we really stopped to verify inputs? A lot of inputs to computer systems today are verified with checksums, control digits, CRCs and reality checks.

Comment: They didn't always double key data entry in the 1960s.   When I was a student submitting programming exercises on punched cards, they never even taught us about double keying.  We made listings of our card decks and proof read those.  It was a couple of years before I saw an industrial scale data entry shop on campus.

Comment: You only need to "double key" when the person doing the keying does not understand what they're keying. This is not a slight on data-entry clerks; however, their job was typing, not programming, and they did not in general possess the expertise to examine a listing (which in itself may cost computer time to obtain) for correctness. Double-keying is faster than 'manual' char-by-char eyeballing.

Comment: For a while there as companies started digitizing records it was cheaper to ship the paper to someplace (the Philippines were common) and have people type them in, usually two separate people entering the data as a verification.

Comment: *Today passwords are the only things we are asked to enter twice.* Nope. Tax preparation software asks to enter bank account numbers twice.

Comment: In the company I worked for at the time it was about 1993.

Comment: Keying data onto cards was often done from handwritten input. Double keying *by two different people* was a check on reading poor quality handwriting, as well as on "fat finger" typing errors. When computer users entered input themselves, the "handwriting check" was irrelevant since (presumably) they knew what they wanted to input!

Comment: @LeoB Not just taxes, bank #'s seem to be always entered twice. All my bill pays work that way.

Comment: Double keying today -- David Holdsworth of the Computer Conservation Society has resuscitated old software from old listings by having two volunteers independently type the source code and then comparing the two. This apparently eliminates a lot of transcription errors. It helps of course if the typists understand the language being used.  (The listings are not good enough quality to use OCR).

Comment: Who exactly is "they"?  And when did "they" ever start verifying everything - not just SOME groups verifying SOME things, as in your example.

Comment: At least on Japanese web sites, double-keying e-mail addresses in web forms is _very_ common.

Comment: @OwenReynolds: I presume you are referring to a bank account number system without any check digits? I've never had to enter a bank account number twice, but [IBANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number) do include check digits and the target bank can be verified from the auto-generated BIC.

Comment: My father's company continued to do double keying after they switched from punch cards to key-to-disk systems. Verification was done by the data entry application rather than the keypunch devices themselves.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm sure numbering schemes that don't use check digits probably exist, but it would seem irresponsible nowadays. The US does not use IBANs as far as I know, but the older [ABA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_routing_transit_number) which contains a check digit. Yet I cannot recall entering my routing or account number only once in any bill pay or direct deposit form. It seems to be the norm for whatever reason.

Comment: Natalie, when you say "`Even in the programmers’ office ***we*** had both machines `", is this a personal recollection? If so, welcome, you can contribute a lot here

Comment: I worked for a service bureau in the late 1980s.  Women double-keyed into  a Mohawk, which transferred data to tape for loading into the mainframe.

Answer (score 30):

Maybe we don't always enter things twice, but verification is still a major part of software engineering.

A lot of pure data entry is still done by double keying, which is to say, the data is entered twice by two different people and the results compared to try to reduce the error rate.

As for programming, if you do it properly, there are code reviews and unit tests and integration tests and system tests. One of the few real innovations in programming since I started professionally in 1987 is "continuous integration" (which isn't really continuous, but never mind), where any change a programmer makes and commits to the codebase is automatically compiled and tested.

So maybe we don't always literally check everything twice, but our modern verification methods are fairly robust and do not represent a backward step since the 1960's.

PS we are also often required to enter an email address twice (which really annoys me since I always copy-paste it), so passwords aren't the only things.

---

Ironically, my answer contained at least one typo. Maybe I should have checked it.

Comment: No, it was the correct decision economically not to check it because the costs of having a typo exceed the costs of checking it to see if there is one.

Comment: @DKNguyen If the cost of having a typo exceeds the cost of checking, isn't that an argument _for_ checking rather than against?

Comment: @Llama My typo. See my reasoning above lol

Comment: Technically, "continuous integration" is not _automatic_ compilation and testing, but _frequent_ building and testing of the entire system (or large sections of it). The originator (or at least popularizer) of the term, Kent Beck, did this manaully on the C3 project; they had a dedicated machine in the middle of the room on which developers would do this at least once a day. (I also use manual CI quite frequently, for reasons there's no space to get in to here.)

Comment: @DKNguyen What was the correct decision economically?

Answer (score 12):

There were two issues, the first being that data entry was not interactive and data was often strangely formatted to get around the constraints of the 80 column punched card so the data wasn't easy to enter. An additional problem that not all punched card machines printed on the cards as holes were punched making verification harder. So type twice to verify became the rule in many places (but not always). The card punch in verify mode would read the card and if your input didn't match, it would alert you and give the possibility to correct, generally by a mixture of duplicating the bad card to the column before the mistake and then manually typing the correction.

Later we went to forms based data entry via screens, even before true interactive computing came into play. The description of a form was sent to a visual display unit, and it looked like the data being entered. It was much easier to see and correct mistakes. The systems also had very limited data checking. They could check if numbers had been typed where alphas were expected or vice versa.

They could still have a verification stage but it was often skipped and if anything, checked from a printout of the entered data later.

Comment: Some of the more _sophisticated_ card punches of the day supported a [Program Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keypunch#Program_card). It provided a _skosh_ of assistance to the operator, but was hardly what we would consider interactive.

Comment: Essentially the program cards could let you SKIP to the next field (a tab function), DUPlicate columns and could lock down the characters available for entry. The DUP function was useful if you had many data records with the same prefix. One such punch was the [IBM 029](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/029.html). The problem was that you had to enter the fields in order and then you didn't actually see what you were typing as the punch/print head covered multiple columns.

Answer (score 4):

Entering data twice squares the probability of a typo going undetected.  Things have moved forward and these days we have the computing power to do some more comprehensive sanity checks ‘if (x = 0) { }’.  I (just) missed the punched-card era but I’d say that pretty much as soon as a programmer was allowed to type commands directly into a computer they would realise that attempting to compile code is much quicker than checking it by hand.

Comment: Uhm, square root means the probability of a typo would *increase*...

Comment: It squares the probability, not square-roots.

Comment: if anyone gets confused reading this post, ask yourself when x^2>x holds true.

Comment: That code compiles does not mean that the entry was error-free.  As an example, consider FORTRAN IV variable names.

Answer (score 2):

> When did double-keying cease to be a common practice in verification?

About the time when data entry became interactive, i.e. when terminals became a thing, which is the late 1960s. On a terminal data entry could be not only easy read and corrected, but as well machine checked right at entry. Something not possible before (*1).

> Even in the programmers’ office

Well, that's a bit extreme, but understandable when punching was done by a dedicated craft who didn't really understood to what she was typing. Saves against a missed comma or space or weird variable name. Saves as well all the paper for redoing and valuable machine time wasted one a missed compile job (*2).

---

> we had both machines

I guess the answer is already in there but maybe hard to imaging in modern times: **Keypunches and card based processing predates all programmable and digital computing.**

Those two keypunch types, straight and verifying (*3), were needed as verification is a different process. There was no way to check any data entry, no processing power for check numbers, valid ranges, format or alike. But what could have been made with (electro-) mechanics already at the turn of the century (20th that is) was comparing the 12 holes at a card position with the 12 levers pulled by a key. A pretty good check when assuming that two different people would not make the same mistake at the same location.

It worked rather well and made lots of sense exactly until the point when computers became interactive - either with the main CPU or local data entry stations (*4).

> and were expected to verify our debugging changes.

Now that's a strong hint that at that time and place it was more a case of the 3 holy rules (*5):

- It's the way we always did it
- We never have done it otherwise
- Who are you to ask otherwise

After all, the chances that the the same person does the same typo at the same location are extreme high, making he whole process somewhat useless.

---

*1 - This is in fact what brought us some of the very first desktop computers: Programmable data entry terminals like the Cogar 4 or Datapoint 2200 - the later being the start of the direct linage to today's x86

*2 - Of course some places also may have made it mandatory for programmers just because it's the way it is - never overestimate the flexibility of bureaucrats.

*3 - Later models combined that into one.

*4 - Well, there were intermediate steps for data entry with key punches that had punch tape control for data entry allowing only certain characters at certain positions of a card and so on, but they were extreme expensive and needed careful setup, so only useful for huge amounts of ever the same cards.

*5 - May sound better in Bavarian

Answer (score -2):

I notice that nobody has actually given the approximate date when verifying everything was abandoned.
I do remember receiving a report from the people looking after my money.  It claimed that some of my money was in a bond earning 200% pa. I wrote to them asking why ALL my money was not invested at 200%. I even sent them a macro which would compare 2 spreadsheets and highlight discrepancies.  It still took them 2 years to amend their reports to show the more accurate return of 2%.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer; it would be more suitable as a comment.  And with reference to the first sentence - there is some dispute as to whether "everything" was verified (by double-keying) in the first place.